# How to write headers list in Python using csvwriter?

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying with the following code

```
cursor = connect.cursor()
    sqlSelect = "SELECT to_char(t.create_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS CreatedDate,t.ticket_number AS TicketNo,p.name AS Priority,t.person_name AS Person,t.subject AS Subject,s.name AS State, to_char(t.close_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS ClosedDate FROM website_support_ticket t INNER JOIN website_support_ticket_priority p ON p.id = t.priority_id INNER JOIN website_support_ticket_state s ON s.id = t.state_id ORDER BY CreatedDate"
    try:
        cursor.execute(sqlSelect)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
        csvFile = csv.writer(open(filePath + fileName, 'w'),
                             delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n',
                             quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, escapechar='\\')

        csvFile.writerows(headers)
        csvFile.writerows(results)
```

When I print the headers
Output is like

```
('headers', ['createddate', 'ticketno', 'priority', 'person', 'subject', 'state', 'closeddate'])
```

and headers just dont write into CSV like headers,
[image: Headers in CSV as of now]

any suggestions how I can print the headers only on the top first row? As of now, every letter of header goes into different rows.

Any suggestion or fix would be really helpful.

Comment: @All, Any ways to apply bold format to headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [writerow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) to add a single row passed as a list:

```py
csvFile.writerow(headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
headers = ", ".join(cursor.description)
```

Not sure if the cursor.description is passed back as a list or not.

So quick check on my own stuff and it comes back as a tuple. Which will screw up the above.

```
headers = ", ".join([i[0] for i in cursor.description])
```

Comment: Use hexbioc's solution, its neater than this

Comment: Yes @Amiga500, tried hexbioc's solution, it worked. Thank you for your efforts as well.